# C# how to read a two digit number from a string to a char

Tags: c#

Hi I know this might be a bit silly. But I need to convert my string to a number, and hence I need to use char to loop through the operators. However if I try to do a two or more digit number the number gets broken into single digits. For example.

```
string str="2+16-42X"

char[] ch=str.toCharArray();
```

the output comes as(ignore the commas)

```
2,+,1,6,-,4,2,X
```

I want to get `2,+,16,-42,X`
any suggestion on how to work around this? Thank you

Comment: How are you going to use this `ch`?

Comment: thats because char = 1 byte ... you cant save '16' on a char - that would be a string ... you can save 16 as ascii code on the char though....

Comment: @mjwills I want to get 16, and 42. Keep the numbers as they are but separated so I can work on them. thank you

Comment: I don't see a problem with getting split numbers (by character). You just need to merge any split numbers in between two operators.

Comment: You need to define rules - I suppose you want to split the input on `+` and `-` before parsing the numbers, but it's unclear to me what you'd want to do with the `X` in the end. Are these the only valid characters?

Comment: You cannot have `char foo = '-42'` or `char foo = '16'`

Comment: so in your example you have minus (-) as a negative number not an operator however the + is an addition. You need to define your rules.

Comment: have you tried using  var result = str.Split(new[] {'+', '-'});?

Comment: @igor-meszaros your solution may be not work .because  he need -42 in answer so he need to specify some rule as he want.

Comment: You're at the start of learning to do *parsing*. Unfortunately, it's a vast subject to cover, but that's essentially what you're trying to do (whilst not knowing the words of art). For example, this bit, splitting the characters apart into logical units is referred to as *tokenizing* (or *lexing*) (and the outputs are referred to as tokens)

Comment: Is there any chance on clarification on the rules here? Or should this be closed as unclear? why is `+16` parsed as `+` and `16` where as `-42` is parsed as `-42`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write a simple lexer:

```
string str="2+16-42X";

StringBuilder currentNumber = new StringBuilder();
List<string> tokens = new List<string>();

foreach(char chr in str) {
    if (Char.IsDigit(chr)) {
        currentNumber.Append(chr);
    }
    else {
        if (currentNumber.Length > 0) {
            tokens.Add(currentNumber.ToString());
            currentNumber.Clear();
        }
        if (chr == '-') {
            currentNumber.Append(chr);
        }
        else {
            tokens.Add(chr.ToString());
        }
    }
}
if (currentNumber.Length > 0) {
    tokens.Add(currentNumber.ToString());
}
```

The `tokens` list contains your numbers and symbols.

Comment: This prints "-","42" instead of "-42"

Answer (score 4):

Here is a RegEx approach

```
string str = "2+16-42X";
string[] result = Regex.Matches(str, "-?\\d+|[+/*X]")
                       .Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Value).ToArray();
```

explanation:

- `-?` optional `-` character at the beginning
- `\d+` one or more digit
- `|` or
- `[+/*X]` one of these characters `+`, `/`, `*`, `X`

https://dotnetfiddle.net/d2ZaGC

Comment: What the OP wants doesn't make a lot of sense, but hallelujah to someone reading the actual question

Answer (score -3):

You can try to use codes below:

```
string str = "2+16-42X";

str = str.Replace("+", " +");
str = str.Replace("-", " -");
str = str.Replace("X", " X");

var numbers = str.Split(' ');

foreach (var number in numbers)
{
    Console.WriteLine(number);
}
```

**Output:**

```
2
+16
-42
X
```

Comment: Can everyone stop adding incorrect answers please... read the question

Comment: `+16` should be `+,16`

Answer (score -4):

Use RegEx:

```
string str="2+16-42X";

var match = Regex.Match(str, @"(\d+|\D)+");

match.Groups[1].Captures.Cast<Capture>().Select(c => c.Value).ToList();
```

returns:

2,+,16,-,42,X

Comment: Expected result is "-42" not "-","42"

Comment: Please remove downvote. When I started writing the answer the "I want to get" was not in the OP question, it has been added after!

Comment: Any way, I don't understand why `-` is to be considered with number, but `+` is not. `-` is an operator just like `+`.

Comment: @Liam I JUST WROTE THE ANSWER, how it could be right if the question was wrong???

Comment: @Teejay Correct.. but that's what OP wants so perhaps clarify with him/her first rather than jumping to throwing an answer. if you posted it after the question was modified, either modify your answer or get rid of it.. clearly it changed context and it isn't your fault but your answer is no longer relevant... can't do anything about it but teach OP to be more detailed in what he wants...

Comment: I think OP is just confused. Clearly, the purpose is to parse a math expression, and math expression are parsed that way (splitting operators from values).

Comment: Unless it's a negative number, but that's his problem if he gets rid of the minus operator.

Comment: Negative number is just a positive number with a minus operator in front of it.

Comment: That's how calculators parses expressions.

Comment: Yes.. which is what he has. As per OPs example there's currently no way of distinguishing the two (the operator and the negative number) is what I meant in my previous comment.

Comment: Anyway my answer was absolutely enough to reach any parsing purpose. But If they want to downvote... amen!

Comment: Yes, it was different at the time I wrote the question. And it is written in comments above that you did not read.